# MongoDB: server instance pool was destroyed issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I never call `db.close()` why this error is happen ?

In my NodeJS service, I have a loop to insert the data to mongo without async/await and response immediate when function is done

```
async function () {
  const dataA = await A.find();

  dataA.forEach((a) => {
    const b = new B({ name: a.name });
    b.save()
  });

  return 200; // response to client with the 200 code
}
```

If while the B still in process to insert new data the function return, the error able happen ?

Comment: Add a full working example. Everything else is just guessing.

Comment: @Marc it's simple, just have a save() calling to save a record in a loop without await. It may the function return before save() is process is done.

Comment: Thats clearly not the problem. `.save()` does not close a connection, break it down,  provide a minimal working example. If you have this problem in your minimal example, its much easier to debug. In your code is absolut nothing that can raise this error.